# How to display Linked PDF documents in WebView Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windows-community-toolkit

Using the Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView in a winforms desktop application, PDF documents linked within the web page, do not display.

I have tried different websites with links to PDF documents. All behaved the same way-They don't display PDF documents. When I tried the same websites in the Edge browser, the linked PDFs display as expected. A link, from a client's web page, to a specific PDF document is as follows: https://xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com/MetaViewer.php?view_id=&event_id=1423&meta_id=92158 (Client name removed for security) When I click on the link it fires the 'NavigationStarting' and the 'NavigationCompleted' event. I haven't been able to determine if other events fire.

```
        WVAgendaPage.Settings.IsJavaScriptEnabled = True
        WVAgendaPage.Settings.IsScriptNotifyAllowed = True
```

I take care if these two settings before the website is loaded.

Since links open and display fine in the Edge browser I was expecting the same behavior with the toolkit based on the Edge rendering engine.

Thanks for your help

RBO

Comment: AFAIK, WebView is only for Html content; it uses the same rendering engine as Edge, but it was not meant as a full feature browser. Navigating to a PDF should be triggering the [WebViewControl.UnviewableContentIdentified Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.ui.interop.webviewcontrol.unviewablecontentidentified).

Comment: Is there a way to display PDF documents in this control the way Edge displays PDF documents?